# Assign a Mesh to a Particle System using Script (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, particle-system

so I have a custom mesh that I have generated using script and I want to assign it in a particle system but nothing will work. The first part of my code is where I delcare a public Mesh in my script just so I can assign the mesh there when I generate it and then take it from there to assign it to the particle system.

```
public Mesh Mesh;
[...]
Mesh = generated_mesh;
[...]
var shape = ps.shape;
shape.enabled = true;
shape.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.MeshRenderer;
shape.mesh = Mesh;
```

The type changed to Mesh Renderer but the Mesh itself doesn't change.

Comment: what is the type of `generated_mesh`? Why the casting? That looks suspicious ^^

Comment: @derHugo well it's also a mesh, idk why I casted it. same thing also happens when I don't use casting, I was just desperate trying solutions so this was the last state my code was in. I don't get an error or something. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seems I was doing it the wrong way all along. I changed the shape type from mesh renderer to mesh and it's all good now. The confusing part is that when I was testing the particle system the only way I could assign the mesh to it manually was through the shape called mesh renderer and not the simple mesh. Anyway, it's all good now.

```
var shape = ps.shape;
shape.enabled = true;
shape.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.Mesh;
shape.mesh = Mesh;
```